# Valid/robust pattern to find the absolute path of the executing Unix shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, absolute-path

I've been using this technique for getting the absolute physical path of the running shell script after reading about it somewhere (I don't remember where).

```
cd $(dirname "$0") && ABSPATH=$(pwd) && cd - > /dev/null
```

It seems like it should work perfectly regardless of whether the script is called from an absolute or relative path, i.e. `script.sh`, `./script.sh`, `../script.sh`, `../../../lib/script.sh`, `/Users/../scripts/script.sh`, from within another script, etc.

In fact this technique seems like it's a pretty solid pattern for absolutifying any relative path.

I know a lot of the techniques for doing this tend to not work on one system or another, for one reason or another. So, are there any compatibility problems with this technique? Should it work with pretty much any Unix OS and shell out there, or are there some potential issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential issue is that it won't follow symlinks (that is, if `"$0"` is actually a symlink to the script, you'll get the directory containing the symlink, not the actual directory containing the script).

Another is that you can't necessarily trust `"$0"`. eg If your script is loaded by one of the `exec` functions, it's trivial to pass in an arbitrary string for `argv[0]`. I use `"$BASH_SOURCE"` instead, though that's obviously bash-specific.

You're missing "s around `$(dirname "$0")`, so it won't work if the directory name eg contains spaces.

I believe this fixes these issues:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$BASH_SOURCE")")" && ABSPATH=$(pwd) && cd - > /dev/null
```

Comment: readlink doesn't exist on some systems, and -e doesn't work on OS X or some other BSD systems. Also, isn't bash unavailable on some systems?

Comment: @Jake Petroules Yeah, I guess you were looking for portability issues rather than quirks with `"$0"` and symlinks, and I've just added a bunch more :P

Comment: If only they thought of setting an environment variable for this back in the day, eh?

Comment: Basically, I've come to understand that this is a virtually unsolvable problem. I suppose the best solution is simply to document the intended usage. I'll accept your answer though since it does point out issues with my proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to continually struggle with this as well. It's a shame that readlink -f|e is not supported across all platforms...

The following works and is portable. It supports relative and nested symlinks  (hence the while loop where we enter the directory.

```
path="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" current="$PWD"
while [ -L "$path" ] ; do cd "$(dirname "$path")" ; path="$(readlink "$(basename "$path")")"; done
ABSPATH="$( cd "$(dirname "$path")" ; pwd -P)"
cd "$current"
```

There's a ton of forks going on and it's not a one-liner so I wouldn't consider it an ideal nor elegant solution... but here it is for the interwebs and I'll see if I can improve with time.

In the past I have used the following pattern (works for absolute symlinks);

```
local path="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -L "$path" ] ; do path="$(readlink "$path")" ; done
ABSPATH="$( cd "$(dirname "$path")" ; pwd -P)"
```

but now mostly use

```
ABSPATH="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")/.." ; pwd -P)"
```